# Where is wallet.dat file?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, windows

I have clearly installed Windows 7 and Bitcoin Core.
There is no Bitcoin folder in {User}/AppData/Roaming... Blockchain is dowloading but I cannot find where it is and wallet.dat also. Anybody help?

My OS in Windows 7.

Maybe I am kind of idiot so I'm pasting PrintScreens with steps I have done

1

[image]

2

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of the linked question. The wallet.dat file will be at `C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallet.dat`

Comment: No there is no wallet.dat. Auxilly there is no Bitcoin or Litecion folder in Roaming. I have hidden and system files visible.

Comment: I connot find any wallet.dat file with Windows Search and also with Total commander search tool. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickODell want TeamViewer to my PC?

Comment: @NickODell you made my question duplicate so prove me tjat there is correct answear in another question!

Comment: As explained in the linked answer, browse to %APPDATA%\Bitcoin

Comment: I did it many times with RUN functionality of the Windows OS

Comment: Any other ideas? It makes me sick :(